# Jquery Load external pages duplicate Id issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Our page loads two external pages (same url) using `$("#div1").load(mypageurl)` & `$("#div2").load(mypageurl).` Each div is opened as a Jquery UI dialog on click of their respective buttons

The external page has some initial load logic to select an internal element and set some value.

Issue is since the URL is same, the id gets duplicated and hence the setting of element does not work for the dialog opened second

If I clear the first div `$("#div1").html("")` everytime before loading the second div, it works alright

Is there any other alternative? Can I do something in my external page to restrict the jquery search of elements within the same page scope?

Pinakin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't it be fine to empty it on close then, or am i missing something??

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   close: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).empty(); 
   }
});
```

Comment: Yeah it will be cleaner and more independent for each dialog

Answer (score 0):

Could you simply avoid the problem by replacing all ids on the loaded page with class references instead?

Comment: the page are independent, by replacing the ids, I might break something